# Mechanism of substitution for disubstituted benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, inductive-effect

[image]

Here,  I count the individual effects of the two oppositely directing groups.  I assume that the deactivation of $\ce{NO_2}$ group at *ortho* and *meta* positions is higher.  While bromination,  I get the product as mentioned above. My query :

**If OH group is more powerful than nitro group,  then why doesn't bromination occur at ortho position on between and para position ?**

If I apply the same logic in the following compounds' bromination,  will the points marked red be the permissible position for substitution (separately)  ?

[image]

Comment: With two oppositely directing groups, I'd expect a complete mess.

Comment: @Ivan...  I'm in a mess...  I saw the first one in a website... Then I did the rest two myself.  However,  I didn't understand the symmetry in the third one...

Comment: What's to understand? One Cl directs with the same force as the other.